# Handle auto layout with iPad views

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want set my constraints programmatically based on view height. For example, i want to set my constraint from view to top equal to (self.view.height)*0.05. However, as far as i understand its impossible, if you try to do that app will raise an exception.

I use masonry (library for helping easy set constraints programmatically), and i found that answer:

```
you cannot relate size attributes (height, width) to position attributes (left, top etc)

If you wanted 20% margin on both top and bottom you could create a constraint which is

make.height.equalTo(superview.mas_height).multipliedBy(60/100.0);
make.center.equalTo(superview.mas_center);
```

Is any way to achieve that point? Thanks.

EDIT:

For example, that code will raise an exception:

```
[imageNewsLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_height)multiplyBy(0.2);
```

Its different from typical programmatically added constraints syntax, but i hope it quit obvious for understand. `That will raise an exception: invalid pairing of layout attributes.`

Comment: @matt my bad. I updated question body.

Comment: @matt would you be so kind to remove downvote, because i update question body to match your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a spacer view, that will be "between" the view and the edge of its parent. If you want to maintain compatibility with iOS 8 and below, use a regular view (empty, transparent), and constrain its height with the multiplier of your choice. If you only target iOS 9 and up, you can use a `UILayoutGuide` which does the same thing but without the cost of an `UIView`.

Comment: you mean that i could use same snippet: make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.mas_height)multiplyBy(0.2); with new invisible view?

Comment: Don't know the exact syntax of `MASConstraintMaker`, but you add an invisible view, a constraint bottom of your view = top of this invisible view, a constraint bottom of the invisible view = bottom of parent view, and a constraint height of invisible view = 0.2 * height of your view (or whatever constraints you actually want to set).

Comment: thank you for explanation. However, that is a bit extra work, i wonder why i cant simple set constraint value simply by passing it multiply result of self.view.height..

Comment: i did try what you said, but, i still got an error - Invalid pairing of layout attributes'... with         make.bottom.equalTo(assistanceView.mas_height).multipliedBy(0.35);

Comment: There's no pairing between bottom and height in my list, only bottom to top, bottom to bottom, height to height.

Comment: i need to some how add constraint to bottom that is equal to some percent of self.view.height.. I cant add fixed value, because of different iPad screen sizes..

Comment: Check the list of constraints I provided above. That should give you exactly what you want.

Comment: im sorry, i dont understand. I edit my post so you can see a picture what i want to do. U suggest: bottom to top, bottom to bottom, height to height. First two (i suppose) is fixed value constraint, and height to height only change height, but not Y position..

Comment: If you just want to adjust the **height** of you view, just make an equal height constraint from the view to the superview with a multiplication factor. Until now you were talking about a bottom margin...

Comment: yes, i could adjust height based of multiplication factor, and i did that with other view, but what if i want my view to be above bottom by point value, that is equal to 0,4*superview.height? Imagine that i set 300 points from myView.bottom to self.view.bottom. That is perfectly fit for iPad Pro, but for iPad 2 300 points will be more then 50% of view height..

Comment: Then do as I told you: add an invisible view that is constrained to fit exactly between the view and the superview, and make this invisible view's height a percentage of the superview.

Comment: i will try to, thank you for your awesome help and patience, and a way to workaround my problem!